# Outlook VSTO Add-In - Cannot install Add-In on Outlook 2019

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, clickonce

I have developed an STVO add-in for Outlook. This add-in works great on both my personal computers (Office 365) and my company computer (also Office 365).

However, an acquaintance for whom I programmed the add-in (Microsoft Professional Plus 2019) always gets the following error (error message translated into English, it may be slightly different): User-defined functions cannot be used in this application because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for XXX or its location is not trusted.

On all other machines I just get a warning that it could be a potential threat, but on the acquaintance's machine the above error message comes up and you can't install it.

What do I need to change so that he can install it too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your add-in isn't signed with a trusted certificate but perhaps yours, Outlook doesn't recognize the publisher. For commercial use, it is recommended to sign the code with a "code signin certificate" issued by a trusted authority so that all customer PCs recognize the certificate. Once you have the certificate, follow these simple steps written in the documentation to sign the project [How to: Sign Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-sign-office-solutions?view=vs-2022)

I hope I have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the certificate before to running the installer - in Windows Explorer, right click on your signed file, Digital Signatures | Details | View Certificate | Install Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Before a solution can run on user computers, either you must grant trust or users must respond to a trust prompt when they install the solution. To grant trust to the solution, sign the manifests by using a certificate that identifies a known and trusted publisher. See [Trust the solution by signing the application and deployment manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/granting-trust-to-office-solutions?view=vs-2022#Signing).

You may find the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022) article helpful.